# Ipvsadm to monitor connections on a load balancer

Tags: linux, ubuntu, monitoring, load-balancing, connection

I am working on to set up Haproxy on a load balancer with two backend web servers in the first period. The problem I am facing is to monitor number of connections to each of my web servers. I have tried do this with the tool `ipvsadm` but after reading about it I am really unsure how to just using the tool to monitor and not use it as a "forwarding - Loadbalancing tool".

I have tried to set it up, but it's totally wrong since I only want to monitor connection to my backend servers with this tool. Do anyone have suggestions how this can be done ? I would also appreciate any tips of how to make graphs also.

To add the Server:

```
ipvsadm -A -t 10.0.33.15:80 -s rr
```

Adding the web servers:

```
ipvsadm -a -t 10.0.33.15:80 -r 10.0.33.18 –m
ipvsadm -a -t 10.0.33.15:80 -r 10.0.33.19 -m
```

Answer (score 1):

[LVS](http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/) (which uses ipvsadm as a cli) and HAProxy both sit at the same functional load balancing layer. You would generally use one or the other, but not both.

HAProxy has the web stats ui which looks like this:

[image: HAProxy Web UI]

You can also access the stats via a [csv file](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#9.1). A github repo has a ganglia [gmetric script](https://github.com/kmullin/ganglia_collection/blob/master/haproxy/haproxy_stats-gmetric.rb) you can use to graph the data.

The [LVS documentation](http://www.austintek.com/LVS/LVS-HOWTO/HOWTO/LVS-HOWTO.monitoring_lvs.html) contains several examples on how to monitor and graph the connections.

Comment: Can you please show me how it can be done with ipvsadm ? My load balancers IP is 10.0.33.15 and the web servers is 10.0.33.18 and 10.0.33.19. I have tried to monitor it, but are unable. My goal is to use a third party tool, not HaProxy since I am benchmarking both Pound and HaProxy.

Comment: watch 'ipvsadm -L' for starters